# How to install Windows 95 from CD-ROM on laptop with no CD drive

Tags: windows, laptop, compact-disc, windows-installation, serial-port

I have a old [Toshiba T4700CT](http://www.toshiba-europe.com/computers/products/notebooks/t4700ct/product.shtm) laptop which I'd like to **install Windows 95 on.** However I own't Windows 95 on CD-ROM and this laptop only has floppy.

I'd prefer not to have to hunt down and pay for a copy of Windows 95 on floppy disks.

**Years ago I managed to use a null modem** or parallel cable to connect a similar laptop to another machine that did have a CD-ROM drive in order to install Windows that how. However I can't remember the exact process I followed and don't know if I'd be able to do such a thing on a modern machine.

Does anyone have a proven process they've used in order to achieve this?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but I'd purchase an external CD/DVD drive. They're very cheap nowadays and they work on other machines too, so its really not a waste of money.

Comment: @LPChip - There are some problems with your suggestion.  Its unlikely the laptop will support booting to an external USB device.  There is still hardware being sold as new today that cannot do this.